# How to show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, where $a$ is in center of the group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a **subgroup** of a group $G$, where $a\in Z(G)= \{x \in G ∣  xg = gx ~ \forall g \in G\}$, the center of the group $G$.

I am unable to show this result. Although I know that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What is meant by $<a>$? Normally it stands for the **subgroup** generated by $a$. If that's the case here then there is nothing to prove and the condition $a\in Z(G)$ is redundant. Do you mean "normal subgroup" maybe?

Comment: In LaTeX you can write "angle brackets" $\langle a \rangle$ as `\langle a \rangle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\langle a\rangle 
$$
for some $a\in G$ is always a subgroup of a group $G$.

It suffices to show that for $n$ and $m$, 
$$
a^na^{-m}\in \langle a\rangle 
$$
by the standard subgroup test. But
$$
a^{n}a^{-m}=a^{n-m}\in \langle a\rangle 
$$
by definition.

Comment: Then there is no need of $Z(G)$

Comment: not at all. This is true for any element $a$

Comment: How to show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a subset of G

Comment: What do you imagine could go wrong?

Comment: Ok, done it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it must be shown that under condition $a\in Z(G)$ the subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ is a normal subgroup.

Observe that e.g. $gaaag^{-1}=agaag^{-1}=aagag^{-1}=aaagg^{-1}=aaa$.

So that $ga^3g^{-1}=a^3\in\langle a\rangle$.

This works for every power of $a$, so $\langle a\rangle$ is normal.

Comment: To show that <a> is a normal subgroup of G, we have to show that $gxg^{-1}\in \langle a \rangle$ where $g\in G$ and $x=a^n\in \langle a \rangle$. You have nicely given an example with $x=a^3$. Would you suggest a way to handle $x=a^n$ very nicely? Although I understand your process

Comment: Would I write $$gxg^{-1}=ga^ng^{-1}=gaa^{n-1}g^{-1}=aga^{n-1}g^{-1}=agaa^{n-2}g^{-1}=aaga^{n-2}g^{-1}=...=a^ngg^{-1}= a^n=x\in \langle a \rangle$$.

Comment: That will be okay. You can also use induction. If $gag^{-1}=a$ and $ga^ng^{-1}=a^n$ then $ga^{n+1}g^{-1}=ga^ng^{-1}gag^{-1}=a^na=a^{n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

It is given that $a\in Z(G)$, then from the definition of center,

$\{ ag = ga ~ \forall g \in G\}$.

now      $ag=ga$

So that $aag=aga$ $\Rightarrow$ $aag=gaa$  ( as $ga=ag$) $\Rightarrow$ $aaag=agaa$ $ \Rightarrow aaag=gaaa$ , proceeding this way you can show $a^n \in Z(G)$   $, n\in N$.

now say for any $a,b \in N$,    $a^na^m \in Z(G)$.

and obviously $ a^0 \in Z(G)$

so $\langle a\rangle \le Z(G)$, as $Z(G) \le G$, $ \langle a \rangle \le G$