# How to show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal Subgroup of a group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

How to show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a **normal subgroup** of a group $G$, where $a\in Z(G)= \{x \in G ∣  xg = gx ~ \forall g \in G\}, \text{the center of the group $G$}.$

With the help of [How to show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, where $a$ is in center of the group $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587565/how-to-show-that-langle-a-rangle-is-a-subgroup-of-a-group-g-where-a-is), it is possible to show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a **subgroup** of a group $G$.

How to prove for normality?

Comment: what? the other answerer correctly intuited that this was your actual question and answered it. Why ask again

Comment: I think maybe what you're not seeing is that, if $a$ is central, then so is every power of $a$. Your entire subgroup is inside the center, so normality is immediate: everything commutes with your subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \in G$ and $x \in \langle a \rangle$. Then there is $n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $x = a^n$.

Then, we know that $gxg^{-1} = (gag^{-1})^n$ (by induction).

However, $ga=ag$, so $gag^{-1} = a$, so $gxg^{-1} = a^n = x \in \langle a \rangle$.

Therefore, $\langle a \rangle$ is normal.

Comment: More generally, any subgroup of the center is normal in the whole group. The proof is even simpler, because you need not make assumptions on what are the elements of the subgroup. One has to know that the center is a subgroup, of course, so the subgroup generated by $a$ is a subgroup of the center.